# Can I stop some code by pressing a button?

Tags: python, selenium

I'm waiting for an element that might or might not show up.
At some point if it doesn't show up I want to be able to press "enter"
and move to some other part of the code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://somelink.com")

Try:
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 1500).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'someid')))
  # I want to be able to interrupt the waiting at some point before the 1500 secs.
except: # if I click on "enter"
  # some other code
  pass
```

I don't know whether it is possible using try/except, timers or not possible at all.
I don't want the script to exit (as with ctrl+c) but rather to execute some other code.

Suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Haven't used selenium but it looks like the code already has you specify how long to wait (in your case 1500 seconds).

Comment: @PQL I want to be able to abort the waiting before the 1500 seconds. Tried to use a variable: with input() as x: WebDriverWait(driver, x).until... which won't work. I'm looking for a general workaround using except if possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you are okay with being asked if you want to continue at regular intervals, in this case 15 seconds, and you want to use except (like you said in your comment), then the following code should work. It isn't the most elegant but it does the trick.

```
try:
    while True:
        try:
            element = WebDriverWait(driver,15).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'someid')))
            break
        except Exception as e:
            do_continue = input("Continue? (y/n)")
            if do_continue == "n":
                raise e
except:

    print 'Doing other code'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this using Try Catch block. The exception which occurs in case element do not show up, mention that exception in catch, and the execution will simple move further in case element does not appear. 
If it do appear, then write the code to handle that element in Try block.

This approach can be tried if you want to avoid manual intervention.